# android - why alertDialog showing on homescreen?

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have a alertDialog prompt during onCreate of Application Class
(i added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />`)

and I have set **setCancelable** to **false** and it did succeessfully prevent user from pressing back button.

This is what I have achieved  so far and this is also what I want.

However, when I press home button, the app did "disappear" but somehow the dialog still showing on home screen, and this is what I DON'T WANT.

What I expecting is that the back button should do nothing(this is what I have achieved).

and when user click home button, the whole app **Including the Dialog** should disappear. But somehow when I click home button the Dialog still appearing on the home screen...

Comment: please put some code of your alertDialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you are creating the [AlertDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html), you probably pass an ApplicationContext instead of just [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html).

By following the android framework guideline, you should not make any UI changes in your Application class. Do it in your Activity of Fragment.

So do this in your Activity class:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
```

or this in your Fragment:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext)
```

Then it will disappear if your application goes into the background state.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
        myDialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog1, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks. It did disable back button but when I click home button the dialog somehow still there on home screen.

Comment: You wan't to dismiss dialog on home button click?

Comment: I want to make dialog "Disappear" on home screen when i click home button.
but when I return back to the app I want to dialog prompt again... just like the rest of the activities.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:-

```
dialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialogs, int keyCode,
                             KeyEvent event) {

            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                 return true;
            }
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
                 // Do your stuff here...
                 return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```